# Winapi: How to get backtrace when gcc program gives segmentation fault?

Tags: c++, c, gcc, window, stack-trace

I'm new with winapi and have windows application that gives me Segmentation fault. I tried proccess explorer to see stack trace but it didn't show the names of the functions. Is there any simple utility or way to make explorer print stack trace? Thank you.

Comment: Run the program in your debugger (gdb). When it crashes, the debugger will be able to tell you the backtrace along with its symbolic data (assuming you've compiled and linked with `-g`).

Comment: I don't know how was it compiled and linked I just need stack trace

Comment: If the symbolic information wasnt compiled/linked into it, you can't get it. Seems pretty obvious, doesn't it?

Comment: Not even Mark Russinovich is good enough to regenerate function names from compiled code.

Comment: when using `gcc`,  compile and link with the `-ggdb` parameter  then when debugging via `gdb` each step shows the line number, the contents for the line, parameter values, function names, etc etc etc.  When running `gdb` and a seg fault occurs use the `bt` (backtrace) command to get the back trace, including line number, function being executed, and a goodly number of other things.   NOTE: if the seg fault occurs in a library function (which usually do not have the debug info included) then that particular line of the backtrace will not produce much useful information.

Comment: if the program is seg faulting, then you are going to need the source code to be able to debug the problem.  So you can compile link the program with all the desired attributes for including debug information.